# Flash Builder: Export profiler results?

Tags: profiling, flash-builder

Is it possible to export the profiling results from Flash Builder?

I need them because I'd like to filter based on method name, but Flash Builder's built-in filtering doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the Flash Builder profiler results but the results appear to be some type of binary format that for now only Flash Builder can parse and view:

[Flash Builder Save Profile Results](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7e46.html#WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7ee4)

> Save profiling data
>
> 1. Select the application in the Profile view.
> 2. Open the drop-down list in the Profile view and select Save. The
>      Browser for Folder dialog box appears.
> 3. Choose a location to save the profile data and click OK. You should
>      create a new folder for each set of
>      profiling data that you want to save.
>      Otherwise, the new data will overwrite
>      the old data if you choose the same
>      folder.
>
> Retrieve saved profiling data
>
> 1. Select the Saved Profiling Data view.
> 2. Click the Open button. The Browser for Folder dialog box appears.
> 3. Navigate to the folder that contains your application’s profile
>      data and click OK. Flash Builder
>      displays the available profiling data
>      in the Saved Profiling Data view. You
>      cannot resume the application in this
>      view, but you can view the memory
>      snapshots, performance profile, or
>      other data that you saved.

Comment: I am not sure about steps 1 and 2, feel like this should be easy, do not know what Adobe means exactly by these steps?  What application?  What drop down list? Thanks

Comment: Same for me.  Staring at the UI and trying to reconcile it with the documentation.  The documentation is not very clear :(

Comment: Figured it out and posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's buried in a totally obscure, non-intuitive location of the GUI.  Open the Profile tab and click the tiny little "v" symbol in the top right of the window then choose Save.

[image: GUI for saving results]

Once you've done that, you can load the results.  Open the Saved Profiling Data tab and choose the open icon and choose the folder you saved the files to.

[image]